# different ways to allocate memory for a data structure on c programming language

Tags: c, structure

On C programming language, I have encountered several ways to allocate memory for a data structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Element
{
    int number;
    struct Element *next;
}Element;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Method NO.1 */
    Element *ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(*ptr1));
    /* Method NO.2 */
    Element *ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    /* Method NO.3 */
    Element *ptr3 = (Element*) malloc (sizeof(Element));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There are no compilation errors.

But I got confused, so what is the difference beteween them, and which one should be preferred?

Comment: ANd what is different here regarding the **allocation**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The best way by, in my opinion, a country mile. Remember that `sizeof *ptr1` is compile-time evaluable so there's no chance of a run-time crash due to dereferencing an uninitialised pointer.
2. Not my favourite way - despite it arguably being the most readable - since you *might* change the type of `*ptr2` and forget to adjust `sizeof Element`. And those kind of bugs are a *nightmare* to track down.
3. Is horrible: the cast is unnecessary in C and is even occasionally harmful. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: For the second method, you said we might change the type of `*ptr2` and forget to adjust `sizeof Element`, could you give me an example?

Comment: Sure, you invent a new structure called `ElementEx` (which is larger than `Element`), and retain `ElementEx *ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(Element));` Eventually your computer will melt.

Comment: Yeah, You are right, with the first method, we can always allocate the exact memory needed for the structure. So I will prefer the first method as you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#1
```

`Element *ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(ptr1));` is wrong, you want to allocate space with the size of an `Element`, not with the size of a pointer to that `Element`,

Change to

```
Element *ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(*ptr1));
```

---

```
#2

Element *ptr2 = malloc(sizeof(Element));
```

You are using the typedef (an alias of `struct Element`), that's fine.

---

```
#3

Element *ptr3 = (Element*) malloc (sizeof(Element));
```

Take a look to [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

---

You can also use:

```
Element *ptr4 = malloc(sizeof(struct Element));
```

even if `struct Element` is typedefed.

Comment: I missed the `*` in fact, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is the preferred way of doing this.  It allocates  space for `sizeof(*ptr1)` bytes, where `*ptr1` is the structure in question.  If for some reason the type of this variable is modified, the above allocation will still work.

The second method is correct because it allocates  space for `sizeof(Element)` bytes, which is the size of the structure.  It is not preferred however, because if the type of `ptr1` is changed for some reason but the expression above is not, you won't be allocating the proper amount of space.

The third method is not correct because [you should not cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: First method seems to be doing `sizeof(*ptr1)`, not `sizeof(ptr1)`, so it's correct.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth OP originally had `sizeof(ptr1)`, then edited after I posted.  I'll update to reflect.